# IMCE file browser doesn't list the files in the Directory path that are uploaded by FTP

Tags: files

I installed `IMCE` and `Filefield_sources` modules to browse the files on the server. my website is on the `localhost` yet. the directory path of `User-1` which is assigned to the administrator is set to `<root>/temp_files` but when I click on the browse file link in the add new content page it only displays files the are uploaded via IMCE file browser not the files I uploaded in the  Directory path. why ?

---

UPDATE:

my OS is Windows so I guest it is not permission related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it!

Instead of using Filefield_source module I should use the [IMCE for FileField](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) module, that's all. Details from project page:

> IMCE for FileField allows users to select files from IMCE File Browser. It supports FTP uploaded files by automatically registering them as IMCE files thus making them usable in a FileField.
>
> How to use
>
> - Go to your FileField settings page.
> - Check the box saying Allow users to select files from IMCE File Browser for this field